# Capacitor Upload to S3 empty file on Android

Tags: android, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I ran into a problem when uploading files to s3.
I use Yandex Object Storage (works also like aws s3 and supports aws-sdk)
I use a presigned url to upload the file. And then I upload the file directly to bucket.

I use Capicatior with VUE. And when you start the dev server from a browser on a PC or in chrome, everything works fine. Files are being uploaded.
But when you open it in the android application, the file is created but loaded empty. I've tried everything I think. I used both the HttpCapacitor and Axios and fetch

The same result is everywhere.

Here is my coder code:

```
// Getting presigned url for upload
const uploadLinkRequest = {
  url: 'https://functions.yandexcloud.net/******',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' },
  data: { action:'getUploadLink',key:this.file.name, type:this.file.type, size:this.file.size},
};

let signedUrl = await CapacitorHttp.post(uploadLinkRequest);
signedUrl = signedUrl.data


let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", this.file); 
let axiosTest = await this.axios.put(signedUrl, formData, {headers: {"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}}); 
console.log(axiosTest)
```

Here is Event Response from android app

```
{
  "data": "",
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {
    "connection": "keep-alive",
    "content-type": "image/jpeg",
    "date": "Tue, 30 May 2023 14:33:10 GMT",
    "etag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"",
    "keep-alive": "timeout=60",
    "server": "nginx",
    "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
    "vary": "Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method",
    "x-amz-request-id": "4524ddaac507b8df",
    "x-android-received-millis": "1685457191681",
    "x-android-response-source": "NETWORK 200",
    "x-android-selected-protocol": "http/1.1",
    "x-android-sent-millis": "1685457191593"
  },
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "adapter": [
      "xhr",
      "http"
    ],
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {},
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    "method": "put",
    "url": "https://*******.storage.yandexcloud.net/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%202012-09-21%2012.35.55%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=YCAJE77M81VmLecdUn1EHKKa3%2F20230530%2Fru-central1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230530T143310Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=ee1c3e50bee3f1b7abe308a5527e7d3e49c7e846554c4ccc23c9b97c5d81ec21&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-amz-acl=public-read&x-id=PutObject",
    "data": "[object FormData]"
  },
  "request": "[object XMLHttpRequest]"
}
```

AND THIS IS FROM SAME PHONE BUT IN CHROME BROWSER

```
{
  "data": "",
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "image/jpeg"
  },
  "config": {
    "transitional": {
      "silentJSONParsing": true,
      "forcedJSONParsing": true,
      "clarifyTimeoutError": false
    },
    "adapter": [
      "xhr",
      "http"
    ],
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "maxBodyLength": -1,
    "env": {},
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    },
    "method": "put",
    "url": "https://*********.storage.yandexcloud.net/Screenshot_2023-05-16-00-23-54-79_cc1c09618b367c44db4f10cd11235963.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=YCAJE77M81VmLecdUn1EHKKa3%2F20230530%2Fru-central1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230530T144335Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-Signature=31bf9657ae55d82d32747f99d491b52d19afa6ce0e34f6f7d25bbad4512d7713&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&x-amz-acl=public-read&x-id=PutObject",
    "data": "[object FormData]"
  },
  "request": "[object XMLHttpRequest]"
}
```

As I see, additional Headers have appeared in the Android app version

```
"connection": "keep-alive",
"content-type": "image/jpeg",
"date": "Tue, 30 May 2023 14:33:10 GMT",
"etag": "\"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e\"",
"keep-alive": "timeout=60",
"server": "nginx",
"transfer-encoding": "chunked",
"vary": "Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method",
"x-amz-request-id": "4524ddaac507b8df",
"x-android-received-millis": "1685457191681",
"x-android-response-source": "NETWORK 200",
"x-android-selected-protocol": "http/1.1",
"x-android-sent-millis": "1685457191593"
```

So what's the problem and why are the files being uploaded empty?? Or they don't load at all. But the file is being created, it's just 0 kb

Please help.

Comment: Can you view the payload?  Is it in fact sending the data?  Or is the data being sent empty.   In troubleshooting this, the first step is to be sure that payload is actually "there"

Comment: Data is exist. In case when i sent in browser its upload correctly to s3 bucket. But in android app, file is empty, but created.